# How to fix errors in xcode when uploading app through organiser?

Tags: ios

Unable to authenticate the package: *******MYNUMBER.itmsp

```
ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.Domain.AppName [AppNAme?.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate.]
```

Also: my [app name] and bundle are totally different names.

I've set the correct provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You **crated that provisioning profile from another computer**. So now you haven't in this computer the **private key in the keychan**. You need to **import the key from your other computer** or you need to **create a new certificate from your keychan on this computer**, upload it on your apple account and follow the usually procedure.